# How to get the corresponding edges from a list of nodes

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, graph-theory, edges

I have a list of nodes in a form similar to this:
Nodelist=[[1,2,3],[4,7,6],[7,2,9]]
Such that there is an edge that connects them, for example 1 is connected to 2 and 2 to 3. These are not the complete set of nodes in my graph.

What I want to do is return a list of edges if there is a connection between the two nodes in Nodelist.
i.e. output=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),...]

What I know already, every node in a sublist of Nodelist is connected, i.e there is an edge between (1,2),(2,3),(3,1).

I hope what i'm asking makes sense, any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to clarify on anything.

Comment: so, basically you want `G.edges` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

[list(combinations(x, 2)) for x in node_list]
```

`combinations` gives all combinations of a list of the given size. 
So `combinations([1,2,3], 2)` would give you `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)]`
Just do that for each of the node_lists.

Comment: Hi, @DroidX86 thank you for the reply. I got the following output [<itertools.combinations object at 0x000001C11CCE0048>, <itertools.combinations object at 0x000001C11CCE0098>, <itertools.combinations object at 0x000001C11CCE00E8>] do you know how i could correct this? I am unfamiliar with this module.

Comment: Put the list just outside of the combinations call instead of outside it